# How to download a file with asp.net Core ?

Tags: c#, .net-core

This is my first question on stackOverflow.
After many research i don't find a way to download a file when the user go on the right URL.

With .Net Framework is used the following code :

```
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                       "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
    response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("FileDownload.csv"));
    response.Flush();    
    response.End();
```

What is the equivalent with .Net core ? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how a user can receive a csv file from your application or upload a csv to your server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you already have a controller, add an Action that return [PhysicalFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.physicalfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for file on your disc or [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for binary file in memeory:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(string fileName) {
    var path = @"c:\FileDownload.csv";
    return PhysicalFile(path, "text/plain", fileName);
}
```

To file path from project folder inject [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and get WebRootPath (wwroot folder) or ContentRootPath (root project folder).

```
    var fileName = "FileDownload.csv";
    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(contentRootPath, fileName), "text/plain", fileName);
```

Comment: I'm using razor pages, so there is no controler.

Comment: The idea still the same, almost no differences, just follow razor pages convention - no attribute on method and use handler to call the method, like 'OnGetFileDownload'. Still you can pass the parameter and you have access to the helper method `PhysicalFile`.

Comment: What does "text/plain" do in your code? Sorry I'm trying to understand it

Comment: @DialFrost this is [media type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types) witch will be returned in [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header to the client, so it can interpret the result correctry. In this case browser will show entire file content as plain text without any styles and scripts.